# Segmentation of connected characters (Python, OpenCV)

Tags: python, opencv, text-segmentation

Given the follow image:

[image: src]

My question is: how can I segment the characters ? How can I divide each char in a single ROI-box ?
It is this even possible while mantaining the chars more or less readable ?

I found [this document](http://en.etsmtl.ca/ETS/media/ImagesETS/Labo/LIVIA/Publications/2013/Ribas_IJDAR_2013.pdf) and at page 6/11 there is exactly what I want to achieve. 
Also, I had some very simple ideas to try a very primitive division of these numbers but all failed.

Do you have some suggestions about what could I do (code or not) ?

Comment: You might want to take a look at  - https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/11/02/watershed-opencv/

Comment: This is the only solution which I didn't tried. I used the code you suggested a few times anyway. Do you think it would worth to try it on charaters like the above ?